# Authorization when creating a file in Javascript in a GitHub repo using API

Tags: javascript, authorization, http-post, access-token, github-api

My goal is to create a static page with GitHub Pages with a simple button.

When I press this button, I want to create a file in the same repository, in the same branch used for GitHub pages.

I read something about Authorization Token to be used in the fetch request to create the file, so I created my Token, I put it into the index.html of the GitHub pages I'm using to access the repository.

Very soon I received an email from GitHub telling me this token is revoked.

The policy is described here: https://github.blog/2015-02-05-keeping-github-oauth-tokens-safe/

My question now is: how can I accomplish this task?

The snippet I was using is the following:

```
async function createNewFileFunction() {
    const user =  { name:  'XXX', surname:  'YYY'  };
    const token = 'ghp_abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890';
    const api_url = "https://api.github.com/repos/my_account/my_repo/contents/test.txt?ref=gh-pages";
    
    try {
        const response = await fetch(api_url, {
                                                   method: 'POST',
                                                   headers: {
                                                                 'Authorization': `token ${token}`,
                                                                 'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'
                                                            }, 
                                                   body: JSON.stringify(user)
                                               }
                                            );
        console.log(await response.json());
        } catch (error) {
            console.log('Request Failed', error);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You put the token in the **index.html** file and this means the world can see the token. That is why you received the message for GitHub as you exposed a token.

GitHub Pages does not support backend code. This means everything is public. You cannot use GitHub Pages to support methods that require a token. The code in a page is executed in the user's browser. You will need to implement backend code or use GitHub Authentication.

Backend code could be a web server, a cloud function like AWS Lambda, or several other services. However, this has a security weakness if you are not using authorization as anyone can call your backend endpoint.

Review these links for GitHub Authentication.

[GitHub: Basics of authentication](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/guides/basics-of-authentication)

[GitHub Authentication](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication)

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

Is there another way to do it without using a backend code on Web Server? For example: one person already authenticated in GitHub, can use these credential to push the code on my repo?

Comment: Sorry I modified the comment because i pressed enter too soon without adding my question.

Comment: That is another question. Create a new post with details. The way you updated your comment is confusing. What other user? Is the other user running in the same browser session - you cannot access credentials in a different browser session. You can create an application that authenticates with GitHub, but that is an entirely different topic.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I will open a new topic.